# Is UiPath Studio considered a 'no-code' or 'low-code' development environment?

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot, uipath-activity, uipath-api

I keep hearing the terms low-code and no-code for development environments. I've always written code in full fledged C# environments, so this UiPath Studio UI is a bit strange to me.

Is UiPath Studio categorized as a 'no-code' development environment? A 'low-code' development environment is another term I've heard.

What categorization does UiPath fall into?

I hope this isn't considered an *opinion based* question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the [official UiPath Studio](https://www.uipath.com/product/studio) websites keywords:

> UiPath Studio gives everyone from business users to advanced
> developers the right automation canvas to build great software robots
> —and organizations the right governance tools to manage it all.

What you have noticed was [**StudioX**](https://www.uipath.com/product/studiox), but that is especially designed for process owners. I don't think that you really want to use that with some C# knowledge already.

Basically it gives you the possibility of no-code indeed. But that depends on what you need to achieve and how no-code is defined. Is coding starting with defining some semi-complex variables already? I would say no, but beginners might say yes, as this paradigm is not existing in a real world.

At the end it is a good mix of both. You need a control flow all the time on long processes. So you e.g. need to know how to use if-statements and that variable type checks are working different on each type. Also, if you go further and having a complex issue that can only be solved with invoking code or creating custom activities, you really need to code. Or you are lucky and find someone else's code on `Go!` or `Connect`. :)

And even further UiPath Studio is just one tool of many. What you can say is that UiPath Studio is never getting a high-level tool for specialists. It's designed for lazy RPA beginners and a little further. And that's good if you ask me.

Answer (score 1):

What constitutes low-code or no-code is certainly up for debate. But UiPath themselves certainly advertise products they consider to be low-code and no-code.

### UiPath StudioX

UiPath StudioX is advertised as being 'low-code.'

> With StudioX, process owners like you get a **no-code tool** to build automations. With no-code drag-and-drop construction, a friendly interface, and pre-designed templates and scenarios, you could launch a robot on your lunch hour. [StudioX Product Page](https://www.uipath.com/product/studiox)

### UiPath Apps

UiPath Apps is advertised as being low-code:

> UiPath Apps includes a **low-code app builder** called App Studio. It lets you build visually appealing professional apps quickly using only a web browser through a rich library of drag and drop controls. [Apps Platform Product Page](https://www.uipath.com/blog/apps-low-code-platform)

### UiPath Studio

So where does UiPath Studio fit in? I'd say Studio certainly allows you to create [UiPath robots](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Create-your-first-RPA-robot-to-UiPath-Orchestrator-tutorial) with a low code approach. It's certainly not 'no-code' as even with loops and if statements you still need to add in some code like statements for the various conditions. And the ability to invoke a full fledged piece of code you've written certainly eliminates the ability to call it 'no-code.'

I think 'low-code' is a fairly accurate description of UiPath Studio.